# UITableView selected cell not getting deselect

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a searchController and tableView in A ViewController where I can search any item from tableView and select that item. I'm saving all selected items in other ViewController B.
Now when I again redirect to A VC where I can see my selected items, I want to deselect some items from selected cells, but I'm not able to deselect the selected cell all other deselected cells I can select without a problem.
When I tap on the selected cell to deselect, I can see it is not calling the below method.

```
tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

In my `viewDidLoad` I have the following properties

```
tableView.isEditing = true
tableView.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
```

And I'm not using any custom cells. Please help me if you have any solution. TIA.

Comment: If you have everything setup properly then it should work fine. You might have missed something. Please share minimum reproducible code.

Comment: @TusharSharma I have added my code below comment, can you please look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue the problem was related to the way I was setting the cell selection I have added the following line in the `cellForRow` method.

```
    if cellItem.isSelected {
       tableView.selectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .none)
    } else {
       tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the selection using your table view data source model.

assume you have an array of objects ex: `var arr:[YourObject] = []`
then add a variable to YourObject ex:  `var isSelected: Bool = false`

in the `cellForRow` method, check your current item selection status and change the cell selection style.

and finally, in `didSelectRow` method, change your current selected object `isSelected` variable status, then reload table view

Comment: I already have an object which has `isSelected` variable and in `cellForRow` I have `cell.setSelected(cellItem.isSelected, animated: false)` you said to check the status of the cell it means I have to check is cell is selected or not and if it is selected then I have to deselect if required right?

Comment: Yes exactly, in `didSelectRow` do this
`arr[indexPath.row].isSelected = !arr[indexPath.row].isSelected` and
`tableView.reloadData()`

so, your table view will refresh its cells selection status from the updated data source.

Comment: When I put `tableView.reloadData()` it is now not letting me deselect the cell.

Comment: can you show me your `cellForRow` and `didSelectRow` methods?

Comment: Which one of them is your data source, `allData` or `favrtItems` ?